# File upload through a modal using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to upload a file through a modal using Ajax. How can I do that?

My modal:

```
<div id="addBtn" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add a medicine</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label mb-10">Generic Name</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="medicine_id" id="medicine_id">
              @foreach($items as $item)
              <option value="{{$item->id}}" >{{$item->generic_name}}</option>
              @endforeach
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label mb-10">Dosage Volume</label>
            <input type="text" name="dosage_name" id="dosage-volume" class="form-control" placeholder="Example: 20mg">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label mb-10">Form</label>
            <input type="text" name="form" id="form" class="form-control" placeholder="Bottle, Tablet">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label mb-10">Price Per piece</label>
            <input type="text" name="price" id="price" class="form-control" placeholder="Price">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label mb-10">Insert a photo</label>
            <div class="panel-wrapper collapse in">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="mt-20">
                  <input type="file" name="photo" id="input-file-now" class="dropify" >
                </div>  
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal" id="save-dosage">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my JavaScript file:

```
function addDosage(url){
    console.log(url);

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:url,
        data:{
            'medicine_id' : $('select#medicine_id').val(),
            'dosage-volume' : $('#dosage-volume').val(),
            'form'  : $('[name=form]').val(),
            'price' : $('[name=price]').val(),
            'photo' : $('[name=photo]').val()
        },
        success:callback,
        error:err
    })

}


function callback(data){
    console.log(data);
}


function err(xhr, reason, ex)
{
    console.log(+xhr.status);
}
```

and this is my controller:

```
 public function storeDosage(ProductsRequest $request){
    $file = $request->file('photo');
    $fileName = uniqid() . $file->getClientOriginalName();

    if(!file_exists('medicine/images')){
      mkdir('medicine/images', 0777, true);
    }
    $file->move('medicine/images', $fileName); 
    if(!file_exists('medicine/images/thumbs')){
      mkdir('medicine/images/thumbs', 0777, true);
    }

    $thumb = Image::make('medicine/images/' .$fileName)->resize(150,150)->save('medicine/images/thumbs/' . $fileName,50);
        //post information to db
    $dosage = $this->dosage;
    $dosage->dosage_name = $request['dosage_name'];
    $dosage->form = $request['form'];
    $dosage->medicine_id = $request['medicine_id'];
    $dosage->price = $request['price'];
    $dosage->save();

    $image = $dosage->photo()->create([
      'dosage_id' => $request->input('id'),
      'file_name' => $fileName,
      'file_size' => $file->getClientSize(),
      'file_mime' => $file->getClientMimeType(),
      'file_path' => 'medicine/images/thumbs'. $fileName,
      'created_by'=> auth()->user()->id,
      ]);
    return redirect()->route('medicineList');

  }
```

but it returns error 500. I think Ajax doesn't accept file upload using Bootstrap modal.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: How about logging the javascript object before sending it with Ajax? That way you can see what you are sending to the server. If ajax does not allow you to upload the file, that's probably because you want to serialize the file to `Base64` first. That way you send a `string` instead of a `filestream`. Your PHP should be able to easily convert that back to a file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can upload the file using bootstrap modal via ajax like this.

In your form tag use attribute enctype and form html will be like below:

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="modal_form_id"  method="POST" >
    <input type="file" name="documents">
 </form>
```

Js code:

```
    var postData = new FormData($("#modal_form_id")[0]);

                         $.ajax({
                                 type:'POST',
                                 url:'your-post-url',
                                 processData: false,
                                 contentType: false,
                                 data : postData,
                                 success:function(data){
                                   console.log("File Uploaded");
                                 }

                              });
```

On your controller side you can do in the function like below to upload image.

```
    if(Input::hasFile('documents')) {

        $path = "directory where you wish to upload file";

        $file_name= Input::file('documents');   
        $original_file_name = $file_name->getClientOriginalName();

        $extension       = $file_name->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileWithoutExt  = str_replace(".","",basename($original_file_name, $extension));  
        $updated_fileName = $fileWithoutExt."_".rand(0,99).".".$extension; 

        $uploaded = $file_name->move($path, $updated_fileName);

        echo $updated_fileName;

    }
```

Comment: How about giving me a controller code that includes also other inputs ?

Comment: I have only explained to upload file if you will add more fields in the form then you can get all other fields also at server side with same code. You can check this by print $_POST on your server side code.

Comment: The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server understands the content type of the request entity (hence a 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request) status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained instructions. For example, this error condition may occur if an XML request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but semantically erroneous, XML instructions.
 
it says like that

Comment: Thank you for this, I just transferred the postData = newFormData.. to my function and it worked

Comment: @A.Sand when answer is helpful to you and provided solution is worked for you then you have to vote up.

Comment: Thanks @SagarArora, you save my lot of time