# laravel: image not being submitted with form

Tags: php, forms, image, laravel, submit

I have this form in a page:

```
<div class="card-block">
{!! Form::open(array( 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'id' => 'AddModel', 'url' => 'model/useradd', 'files' => true)) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="picture">Picture</label>
    @if( (new Jenssegers\Agent\Agent)->isMobile() )
    {!! Form::file('image', ['id' => 'modelpic', 'accept' => 'image/*', 'capture' => 'camera'])  !!}
    @else
    {!! Form::file('image', ['id' => 'modelpic']) !!}
    @endif
    <br/>
</div>
<div id="imagePreview" style="display: none;"></div> /** here I show preview of the image through JS */
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Submit', array('id' => 'AddBtn', 'class' => 'btn btn-default' )) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

in my controller:

```
public function preview(Request $request)
{
dd($request->file('image'));
}
```

result of dumping = `NULL`

I don't understand what's the catch here. I have an identical form in another page that is working normally.

by validating request I get the error "image is required"

```
$this->validate($request, [

'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|image|image_size:>=640'
]);
```

new info:

There must be a problem with the javascript because removing it the controller works normally:

this is the JS

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("body").on("submit", "#AddModel", function (e) {

            var form = $(this);

            $.ajax({
                url: form.prop('action'),
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {

                console.log(data);


                },
                error: function (textStatus) {

                    {


                        var json = JSON.parse(textStatus.responseText);


                        console.log (json);


                    }

                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
```

solved, thanks @sagar

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("body").on("submit", "#AddModel", function (e) {

            var form = $(this);

            var postData = new FormData($("#AddModel")[0]);

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:form.prop('action'),
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                data : postData,
                success:function(data){

                    console.log(data);

                },

                error: function (textStatus) {

                    {


                        var json = JSON.parse(textStatus.responseText);


                        console.log (json);


                    }

                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: try change to `dd($request->file('modelpic'));`

Comment: also on the validate use modelpic

Comment: modelpic is the id of the div here `<input id="modelpic" name="image" type="file">` .. the name is "image" anyway nothing changes by modyfing as per your suggestion

Comment: remove **files => true** and tell us if it's appear the value using **$request->input('file')**

Comment: the problem when you try to make the preview not when you store. isn't?

Comment: the preview in the div works, the image is shown. The problem is in storing

Comment: paste the result of dd($request->all())

Comment: removing files => true and dumping $request->input('file')  returns null again

Comment: There is a `if` condition when you are outputting the input for your file, which one is being echoed?

Comment: `{!! Form::file('image', ['id' => 'modelpic']) !!}` as I am not on mobile.

Comment: removing the javascript everything works, I updated the question with the JS

Comment: post your form data like  var postData = new FormData($("#form_id")[0]); This will post image too . more details check my answer

Comment: you may vote up so that it help others too. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload image using ajax:

Do it like:

You can upload the file using ajax like this.

In your form tag use attribute enctype and form html will be like below:

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="modal_form_id"  method="POST" >
    <input type="file" name="documents">
 </form>
```

Js code:

```
           var postData = new FormData($("#modal_form_id")[0]);

                 $.ajax({
                         type:'POST',
                         url:'your-post-url',
                         processData: false,
                         contentType: false,
                         data : postData,
                         success:function(data){
                           console.log("File Uploaded");
                         }

                      });
```

On your controller side you can do in the function like below to upload image.

```
if(Input::hasFile('documents')) {

    $path = "directory where you wish to upload file";

    $file_name= Input::file('documents');   
    $original_file_name = $file_name->getClientOriginalName();

    $extension       = $file_name->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $fileWithoutExt  = str_replace(".","",basename($original_file_name, $extension));  
    $updated_fileName = $fileWithoutExt."_".rand(0,99).".".$extension; 

    $uploaded = $file_name->move($path, $updated_fileName);

    echo $updated_fileName;

}
```

More details :

[File upload through a modal using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42298502/file-upload-through-a-modal-using-ajax/42298969#42298969)

Comment: I'll try but I am not using a modal, the form is in a page. What I am trying to so is get the submitted data then show a preview of the post so to confirm or abort submission. Confirm stores in the DB, abort goes back to form.

Comment: now that I am thinking this better maybe I shouldn't pass the data to the controller for preview purpose but to the ajax query directly and then show the preview box with confirm button.

Comment: @Chriz74 in the answer i have taken modal form just as an example . you can post normal form data using above code . The only thing you need to change is the way to get form data like: var postData = new FormData($("#form_id")[0]); it is not depend upon the modal form or the page form

Comment: I tried your code, it's working. I'll update the question with the JS I used.

Comment: one thing I don't get though. If I log formData it seems to be empty, I can't find the data being submitted by form but it's working.

Comment: @Chriz74 can you please elaborate it as i am un able to understand your last comment.

Comment: `var postData = new FormData($("#AddModel")[0]); console.log(postData);` the resulting log shows Null values everywhere, shouldn't it contain the values submitted ?

Comment: @Chriz74 great question buddy. but i have not any exact idea why it is happening so i don't want you misguide by giving some answer. for more details you can read here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Answer (score 0):

This code checks if request has a file if yes then names it and then moves the files to a folder in public dir.

```
if($request->hasFile('modelpic')) {
        $file = Input::file('modelpic');
       //get file extension
        $name = 'image'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
       //move file to public/images dir
        $file->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);
    }
```

Comment: thanks but the file should be in request anyway, I am storing the image differently after modyfing with imagemagick. The problem is the image is not submitted at all by the form.

Comment: using my `if` statement check if there is a file in request. include an echo in the `if`

Comment: @Chriz74 can you check the code again with the name field (image) instead of id(modelpic)?

Comment: already done, nothing. Here is the result of $request->all(); `array:1 [
  "_token" => "YNDRn9VDR5W3nv6A4P8W7WeUWun77fnvjDZYq3bE"
]` .. this makes no sense to me

Comment: add textbox field to the form and check if it's appear in $request->all()

Comment: removing the javascript everything works, I updated the question with the JS

Answer (score 0):

Images are submitted with multiple part request due to size use (`Multipart-form-data`) in form tag.
Like this,

```
<div class="card-block">
  {!! Form::open(array( 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'id' => 'AddModel', 'url' => 'model/useradd', 'files' => true,'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')) !!}
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="picture">Picture</label>
  @if( (new Jenssegers\Agent\Agent)->isMobile() )
   {!! Form::file('image', ['id' => 'modelpic', 'accept' => 'image/*', 'capture' => 'camera'])  !!}
  @else
   {!! Form::file('image', ['id' => 'modelpic']) !!}
  @endif
<br/>
</div>
<div id="imagePreview" style="display: none;"></div> /** here I show preview of the image through JS */
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::submit('Submit', array('id' => 'AddBtn', 'class' => 'btn btn-default' )) !!}
   {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

Comment: I believe `'files' => true` adds `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: Then You can use `if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
    //code here
}`

Comment: the multipart/form-data is already there, that form translates to `<form method="POST" action="http://project.dev/model/useradd" accept-charset="UTF-8" autocomplete="off" id="AddModel" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Although incredibly, specifying it as you suggested magically works! But looking at the source with and without that specification nothing changes!

Comment: You should check you `post-max-size` and `upload-max-size` in php.ini file

Comment: Then I believe there must be issue with `boundy limit` on multipart request.

Comment: how could this work if the resulting html is identical with or without `'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'` ?

Comment: try  `route` instead of  `url` in form
`{!! Form::open(array( 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'id' => 'AddModel', 'route' => 'model/useradd', 'files' => true,'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')) !!}`

Comment: Route [model/useradd] not defined

Comment: I spoke too early, it doesn't work. it's intermittent. It will return all the other input without image or the image alone.

Comment: removing the javascript everything works, I updated the question with the JS